# WEBP file corruption

Tags: nginx, webp

I have a background image for a website. Using PNG it works just fine. I created a .webp file using `cwebp` and the .webp file displays just fine locally in Preview or in Chrome. The website using it is served as static files using NGINX in a container that happens to be hosted in Azure. I can access the site and the background image via Azure Front Door or on an exposed IP. I have tried with GZIP on and off (NGINX config and Azure FD Config). If I serve the image running the react scripts locally it works.

But in all cases when running in a container in K8s on Azure, the PNG file works fine but the WEBP file fails to display - sometimes you get a brief flash of a corrupted image as it loads. Examining the file after downloading it has a different length.

It appears that NGINX is corrupting the file. The NGINX conf line that serves the file is the simplest possible `try_files $uri /index.html;`. I have `proxy_http_version 1.1;` and the image is served with the correct mime type.

As you can see below the file retrieved by the browser is 3,653,289 bytes but the file being served should be 3,653,334 bytes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the culprit was in fact the `cwebp` tool from Google. Using a different tool to create webp files has created files that work just fine.

It's still a mystery why the files worked locally in Preview and Chrome, but not when copied to a web server maybe it's related to the length issues others have reported in webp file corruption?